# Kotlin Android Extensions does not work in a library type module

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to implement kotlin android extensions to use the @Parcelize annotation, if I implement it in the application's module ('com.android.application') it works without problems, but when I try to use it in a library-type module ('com.android.library') it does not work for me.

The configuration of my gradle is the following:

Build.gradle // app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

allOpen {
  annotation 'com.juanlondono.app.soldi.testing.OpenClass'
}

androidExtensions {
  experimental = true
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  // ------------------------- KOTLIN ------------------------- //
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11"

 ... // Other Dependencies

}
```

Build.gradle // library

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    
      // ------------------------- KOTLIN ------------------------- //
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11"
   
    ... // Other Dependencies
    }
```

To make the configuration of kotlin android extensions I base myself in the following guide: [Kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

After making the previous configuration I try to implement the @Parcelize annotation and it does not work I get the message of **unresolved reference Parcelize.**

adding

```
androidExtensions {
   experimental = true
}
```

At the gradle of the library, the following error occurs:

```
Cannot invoke method get() on null object

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:prodDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':model'.
      > Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
         > Cannot invoke method get() on null object
         > Cannot invoke method get() on null object
         > Cannot invoke method get() on null object
         > Cannot invoke method get() on null object
```

For now, the implementation of Parcelable is done manually.

**UPDATE**

recently kotlin extension is deprecated in favor of kotlin-parcelize to make the project work the following must be changed:

**STEP 1:** Update to latest kotlin version(1.4.20) or newer

**STEP 2:** replace `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`
with this `apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'`

**Step 2:** Remove this code from the android {}

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

**Step 3:** Replace old import `import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize`
with new import `import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize`

Comment: What exactly does "it does not work for me" mean? What are your precise symptoms?

Comment: when I try to use the annotation @Parcelize it tells me unresolved reference Parcelize, and if I try to import manually, import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize does not work either

Comment: Your library `build.gradle` file does not show the `androidExtensions { experimental = true }` closure. Do you have it?

Comment: when I add `androidExtensions {experimental = true}` to the gradle of the library, gradle not sync,

Comment: Kotlin version 1.1.4 or newer?

Comment: Kotlin version 1.3.11

Comment: Is your library Android or Java. You can't add to Java library.

Comment: @HemanthSTobi the project is of type `com.android.library`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just rehearsed with the version of `Kotlin 1.3.50` and it works correctly with the following configuration:

The project must be of type `com.android.application` or`com.android.library`. In my case I am using a project of type `android.library`.

**build.gradle (library)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
  ...
}

androidExtensions {
  experimental = true
}

dependencies {
  ...
}
```

**Model Class**

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Test(val prop: String) : Parcelable
```